# Error in returning list of objects for the spring boot application in microservices development

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, collections, microservices

- I followed the microservices tutorial from youtube to create independent services (spring boot Application)
- I created a service implementation java file providing method definitions for the request mapping URL (/catalog/userId) for the read operation
- To the above requested URL, returning a list of objects as the response body (HTTP response) for the HTTP read request
- In the java, error occurring for the function definition of sending a list of objects
- The error occurs in line 17 of MovieCatalogResource.java stating the illegal start of expression, unexpected token
- I researched for the error but still I am struck with the execution
- can you guys kindly provide your help to resolve issue with your suggestions
- Providing the code below

CatalogItem.java

```
package com.example.moviecatalogservice;

public class CatalogItem {
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    private int rating;
    public CatalogItem(String name, String desc, int rating){
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    public int getRating(){
        return rating;
    }
    public void setRating(){
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDesc(){
        return desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(){
        this.desc = desc;
    }
}
```

MovieCatalogService.java

```
package com.example.moviecatalogservice;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.an notation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/catalog")
public class MovieCatalogResource {
    @RequestMapping("/{userId}")
    //public List<CatalogItem> getCatalog(@PathVariable("userId") String userId){
    public List<CatalogItem> getCatalog(@PathVariable("userId") String userId){
        return Collections.singletonList(
                new CatalogItem(name: "transformers", desc:"Test", rating:4)
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: IMHO please write more code to make yourself comfortable in syntaxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
new CatalogItem(name: "transformers", desc:"Test", rating:4)
```

To

```
new CatalogItem("transformers", "Test", 4)
```

> You must have a matching CatalogItem() constructor in CatalogItem
>   Entity Or Model

After a `change at line no 17` of `MovieCatalogResource.java` it will look like as below

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/catalog")
public class MovieCatalogResource {
    @RequestMapping("/{userId}")
    //public List<CatalogItem> getCatalog(@PathVariable("userId") String userId){
    public List<CatalogItem> getCatalog(@PathVariable("userId") String userId){
        return Collections.singletonList(
                new CatalogItem("transformers", "Test", 4)
        );
    }

}
```

---

Working Example

**Controller.java**

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public List<User> getUser(@PathVariable(name="id") int id)
    {
        return Collections.singletonList(
                new User(1,"username")
        );
    }
```

**User.java**

```
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    public User(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public User() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }


}
```

Tested using Postman
[image]

Comment: Hello @tamil-cool, Have you solved the issue with the above solution?

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... the code worked out well.. your suggestions are very helpful and provided with meaningful examples

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this :

```
new CatalogItem(name: "transformers", desc:"Test", rating:4)
```

instead of this :

```
new CatalogItem("transformers", "Test", 4)
```

at line no 17 of MovieCatalogResource.java?

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... the code worked out well.. your suggestions are very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Change  the below statement from new CatalogItem(name: "transformers", desc:"Test", rating:4) to  new CatalogItem("transformers","Test",4)

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... the code worked out well.. your suggestions are very helpful